# Separate connected objects and single objects from an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I am working on an image in Matlab as shown in link http://lyremjeni.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/tocleanblobs.jpg

I want to separate connected/grouped cell blobs and single cell blobs from image and then display them in separate figures. kindly suggest how can i achieve this separation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two solutions you could use, the 1st one using [bwconncomp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwconncomp.html?searchHighlight=bwconncomp) which finds connected elements in a binary image, and the 2nd one using [imfindcircles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.html?searchHighlight=imfindcircles), which believe it or not finds circles! Therefore in instances where the objects to detect are not all circles the 1st solution would be preferred.

I prefer the first one, as it discriminates between single circles and clusters of circles, which is what you asked, whereas the method using imfindcircles is rather useful for identifying individual circles, so not necessarily clusters. Here is the code:

**1- bwconncomp**

```
clear
close all
clc

A = imread('Circles.jpg');
BW = im2bw(A); %// Convert to binary with threshold of 0.5. 

CC = bwconncomp(BW); %// Find connected components.
```

This is what CC looks like, i.e. a structure with a couple fields:

```
CC = 

    Connectivity: 8
       ImageSize: [256 256]
      NumObjects: 15
    PixelIdxList: {1x15 cell}
```

As you see there are 15 objects detected.

Now loop throught he objects and plot/draw them:

```
BW2 = zeros(size(BW)); %// Create dummy image for display purposes.
imshow(BW2)
hold on

for k = 1:CC.NumObjects %// Loop through each object and plot it in white. This is where you can create individual figures for each object.

    PixId = CC.PixelIdxList{k}; %// Just simpler to understand

    if size(PixId,1) ==1 %// If only one row, don't consider.        
        continue
    else
    BW2(PixId) = 255;
 %figure(k) %// Uncomment this if you want individual figures.
    imshow(BW2)
    pause(.5) %// Only for display purposes.
    end
end
```

If you run the code you will see that it actually creates only one figure; this is only for demonstration but if you want each object in a figure just add `figure` in the loop where I noted to create one.

**2- imfindcircles**

Here the principle is very simple, as the algorithm detects circles and stores their radius and center coordinates. It's then quite easy to plot/crop them to get them individually. As I said however it does not detect clusters of circles, but I thought it could be good to know anyway.

Here I create a figure for each circle detected.

```
A = imread('Circles.jpg');
[centers, radii, ~] = imfindcircles(A,[5 25],'Sensitivity',.95,'ObjectPolarity','bright');

A_crop = cell(1,numel(radii));
for k =1:numel(radii)    

%// Since imcrop requires a cropping rectangle, we need to fin the x and y coordinates of the lower-left corner, as well as the width and height of the rectangle. 
    x = centers(k,1);
    y = centers(k,2);
    r = radii(k);   
   A_crop{k} = imcrop(A,[x-r y-r 2*r 2*r]); %// [x y width height]
   imshow(A_crop) %// New figure
   pause(0.5) 
end
```

If you want to see all the circles outlined, you can use this:

```
imshow(A);
 hold on

 viscircles(centers, radii,'EdgeColor','b');
 hold off
```

giving the following:

[image]

Comment: Good job my friend! +1

Comment: Thanks Ray! Let's say the question was not of the highest quality but it was too hard to resist answering it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to separate single blobs from grouped blobs (this was what I understood from your question), try the code below.

It basically:

- Segment the image using a fixed threshold (0.5) since the image is just black/white
- Find connected components
- Calculate a metric for each connected component. The metric is `4*pi*area/perimeter^2`. This metric is only 1 for a perfect circle and less than 1 for any other shape
- Use the metric to separate single blobs from grouped blobs (single blobs will be very similar to a circle, grouped blobs will not)

**Code:**

```
function[single, grouped] = ipl_separateblobs(I)

% I is assumed to be a grayscale image

% Step 1: Convert image from grayscale to binary
BW = im2bw(I); 

% Step 2: Find connected components
[L, n] = bwlabel(BW); 
stats = regionprops(L, 'Area', 'Perimeter', 'Image');

% Step 3: Separate objects (avoiding very small objects)
MIN_AREA = 10; 
MIN_CIRCLE_METRIC = 0.75; 
single= [];
index_s = 0;
grouped = [];
index_g = 0;

for i=1:n
    if(stats(i).Area >= MIN_AREA)
        metric = (4*pi*stats(i).Area)/(stats(i).Perimeter^2);
        if(metric >= MIN_CIRCLE_METRIC)            
            index_s = index_s + 1;            
            single{index_s, 1} = stats(i).Image;
            single{index_s, 2} = metric;                
        else
            index_g = index_g + 1;
            grouped{index_g, 1} = stats(i).Image;
            grouped{index_g, 2} = metric;                   
        end
    end
end

% Display original image
figure('Name', 'Original image');
imshow(I);

% Display single objects
figure('Name', 'Single blobs'); 
m = ceil(index_s/3); 
for i=1:index_s
    subplot(m, 3, i);
    imshow(single{i,1});
    title(['Metric: ' num2str(single{i,2})]);    
end

% Display grouped objects
figure('Name', 'Grouped blobs'); 
m  = ceil(index_g/3);
for i=1:index_g
    subplot(m, 3, i);
    imshow(grouped{i, 1});
    title(['Metric: ' num2str(grouped{i, 2})]);
end

end
```

You may need to adjust the value of `MIN_AREA` and `MIN_CIRCLE_METRIC` according to your needs:

- Connected components whose area is less than `MIN_AREA` will be skipped (to avoid noise)
- Connected components whose metric is greater or equal than `MIN_CIRCLE_METRIC` are considered as a single blob; otherwise they are considered as a grouped blob.

Please don´t be afraid to ask any doubt you may have.